# Ошибка Severity: Warning в Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Подскажите в какое место копать, почему не отрабатывает `filemtime` ?

Уверен что ошибка какая нибудь глупая, но так всегда бывает сложные вещи быстро решаешь, а на банальных вещах застреваешь на целый час )

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="icon" href="<?=base_url();?>public/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Tradecoin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url();?>public/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url();?>public/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url();?>public/css/style.css?<?php filemtime(base_url().'public/css/style.css'); ?>">
</head>
<body>
...
```

Сам код ошибки

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: filemtime(): stat failed for http://tradecoin.local/public/css/style.css

Filename: views/home_view.php

Line Number: 12

Backtrace:

File: D:\OSPanel\domains\tradecoin.local\application\views\home_view.php
Line: 12
Function: filemtime
```

Что я пытаюсь делать: добавляю параметр к файлу в виде даты UNIX timestamp, чтобы при его изменении обновлялся его кеш

Comment: Совет: Вы вроде взяли `MVC` фреймворк а паттерны не соблюдаете. `CI` - голый, чтоб правильно на нем писать его сначала надо подтюнить. 1) В `V` - НИКОГДА не должен быть `PHP`, только языки фронта и ваш псевдо-язык, шаблонизатора (придется его завести). 2) В `C` - никогда не должны быть части содержимого `V`, т.е. не должно быть чтобы было типа: `$test = '<b>Титл</b>;'. Задача контроллера указать какие вьюхи идут на выход и каким вьюхам скормить массивы с данными (условия и манипуляции с масивами - можно). В одной `M` никогда не должно быть полей другой `M`. Все манипуляции с БД только в `M`.

Comment: @Manitikyl, спасибо за разъяснение, для проектов общего пользования как раз все это соблюдается, если что то только для личного пользования то совсем немного позволяю себе грешить для экономия времени ヅ

Comment: Я просто дал инфу (для справки, в случае, если вы не знали), бить вас палками никто и не собирался))

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url();?>public/css/style.css?<?=filemtime('./public/css/style.css');?>">
```